# One dataframe column to filter another

Tags: r

I have two dataframes.  Here's and example of my first:

```
    index   anom
1   50      400
2   60      600
3   70      550
...
```

The previous dataframe has a column 'index', which are the rows I need to pull out of the following dataframe example:

```
    date   value
1   5/2/14 200
2   5/3/14 300
3   5/4/14 400
...
```

so basically, I need one dataframe column (the 'index' column in the first dataframe) to be put in a list of some sort.  Then I need to use that list to select rows in the second dataframe.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Not sure I understand this properly.  May be `df2[df1$index,]`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
d.a <- read.table(file=textConnection("index   anom
1   2      400
2   3      600
3   1      550
"))

d.b <- read.table(file=textConnection("date   value
1   5/2/14 200
2   5/3/14 300
3   5/4/14 400
"))

merge(d.a, d.b, by.x="index", by.y="row.names")
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for clarity sake, lets say you have:

```
df1 <- data.frame(index=c(50, 60, 70), anom=c(400,600,550))
df2 <- data.frame(index=c(20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70), date=c("4/29/14", "4/30/14", "5/1/14", "5/2/14","5/3/14","5/4/14"), value=c(1,2,3,200,300,400))
```

You didn't have the index listed in your example of data frame 2, but I assume it's there. Then, use the index from df1 to do an inner join of the data in df2 and return the columns of interest:

```
df3 <- merge(data.frame(index=df1$index), df2)[,c("date","value")]
print(df3)
    date   value
1   5/2/14 200
2   5/3/14 300
3   5/4/14 400
```

Is that what you're hoping for?